# Accessing cell 1 in Telerik RadGrid from cell 3 (not databound)

Tags: c#, vb.net, telerik, eval, radgrid

My grid is 5 columns, an "Event" column followed by Q1 through Q4. One of the quarter columns is editable at any given time, the other three are labels. Here is the code I use to determine which to show (q defined elsewhere):

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Q2" DataField="Q2" UniqueName="Q2">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <% If (q = 3) Then%>
            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="rntb_Q2" runat="server" Type="Number" ShowSpinButtons="true" Value='<%# CInt(Eval("Q2")) %>' Width="50px" CssClass="short" MinValue="0">
                <IncrementSettings InterceptArrowKeys="false" InterceptMouseWheel="false" Step="1" />
                <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" GroupSeparator="," />
            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
        <% Else%>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Q2" runat="server" Text='<%# If(Eval("Q2") Is Nothing, "0", Eval("Q2")) %>'></asp:Label>
        <% End If %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

This code all works fine; the problem is when I want to change *one row* to display a label all the time. I tried `If ((q = 3) AndAlso (Not GetDataItem("EventDesc").ToString.ToLower = "total error doses"))` as well as `If ((q = 3) AndAlso (Not Eval("EventDesc").ToString.ToLower = "total error doses"))` but with both I receive an error about not being able to use Eval, etc outside of data bound.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I was trying to do was change whether a RadNumericTextBox or Label was displayed. This achieves the result without accessing the contents of another cell directly. It uses the .ItemIndex property to determine what controls should be visible.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Q2" DataField="Q2" UniqueName="Q2">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <% If (q = 3) Then %>
            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="rntb_Q2c" runat="server" Type="Number" ShowSpinButtons="true" Value='<%# Eval("Q2") %>' Width="75px" CssClass="short" Visible='<%#If(TryCast(Container, GridDataItem).ItemIndex < 9, True, False) %>'>
                <IncrementSettings InterceptArrowKeys="false" InterceptMouseWheel="false" Step="1" />
                <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" GroupSeparator="" />
            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Q22" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q2") %>' Visible='<%#If(TryCast(Container, GridDataItem).ItemIndex < 9, False, True) %>'></asp:Label>
        <% Else %>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Q2" runat="server" Text='<%# If(Eval("Q2") Is Nothing, "0", Eval("Q2")) %>'></asp:Label>
        <% End If %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```